# How to do file integrity monitoring for ClickHouse?

Tags: merge, clickhouse, integrity

I have a use case where I store logs in ClickHouse database partitioned by day. Once logs are written they will not be updated. I want to monitor the integrity of the data files to validate they are not modified. A simple solution is to calculate md5 hash of all files of that partition. But ClickHouse performs background merges based on some kinds of "heuristic" algorithms. So the question is if I stop inserting rows into one partition and I run OPTIMIZE TABLE .. FINAL on that partition, is it guaranteed that no merge will happen for that partition anymore? If so, I think I can use this md5 hash approach.

The intention of this use case is to check for hypothetical “hacker” that may intentionally modify the files.

Comment: it is guaranteed that no merge will happen for that partition anymore, though you can run `alter table add column / update / delete` and then check sum will change.

Comment: you can use `system.parts` `hash_of_all_files / hash_of_uncompressed_files
uncompressed_hash_of_compressed_files` instead of  md5 hash

Comment: That's the information I was looking for! Thanks for the answer, Denny.